# CSS div container 100% of whole site

Tags: css, height

I know this issue has been commented on several times already but somehow I still seem to miss something.
Every div, including html and body has height of 100% but the div still stops at the height of the browser windows (see red line here: http://www.themasquera.de)
So somehow somewhere the content inside the divs float above the main wrapper.. but I don't see where and why. Any help?

Comment: we need to see some html and css

Comment: Thank you, min-height works.. Sorry for stupid question. Is that why I am "temp" now?? Update: Actually, doesn't work unfortunately. Now smaller pages dont have the background for the full height (http://www.themasquera.de/games/).. ?